# Windows proxy settings updated automatically

Tags: windows, proxy

While trying to set proxy settings in my Windows machine registry I found an interesting thing that I hope you will be able to help me with.

The proxy settings that are set on my machine are:

```
ftp=127.0.0.1:80;http=127.0.0.1:80;https=127.0.0.1:80` -> ProxyServer
```

In `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

These proxy settings look like maybe some type of virus that sends all of you browsing data to somewhere.

---

But the `ProxyEnable` key is set to `0`, so practically the proxy settings do not really work.

Every time I attempt to change the proxy settings, after few seconds they are restored to the default shown above.

I cannot find any software on my computer that will cause this kind of thing.

It is not my antivirus.

Comment: you do know what 127.0.0.1 is, don't you?

Comment: is it a company machine or your personal machine? Is Automatically Detect Settings set to off?

Comment: Google is full of reports of this problem - have you checked other people's reports?

Comment: @schroeder of course I know what 127.0.0.1 but you should never be naive.. You can never know from where or how the next virus is going to come from. This is my personal machine. I found out what it is. There is some extension on my Chrome (which I don't use anymore) that changes the proxy settings. This extension is OK and is used to set the proxy server on machine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you answered your own question, you should submit it and choose it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried to change your question a little bit readable, I think your chances to a good answer would be higher if you continued this.

Comment: @schroeder actually I was mistaken.. This proxy settings resetting stopped, but it wasn't the extension. I tried to reinstall it and the settings are still the same. I am still looking for the cause of this proxy server settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hijack virus rootkit. You need to remove the root kit that  keeps putting it back in with tdsskiller, then Malwarebytes and done

Comment: FYI. . . A link or two to the tools you suggest would be nice as well.